# Change output result color dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I try to change the color of a javascript result depending it's positive or negative.
I made many tries but not found the solution. Below my last try:

Javascript:

```
var calc = (a + b) * c;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calc;
(0 < calc) ? document.getElementById('result').style.Color='green':document.getElementById('result').style.Color='red';
```

Html:

```
Result: <output id="result"></output>
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is better:

```js
var [a,b,c] = [1,2,3]
var calc = (a + b) * c;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calc;
document.getElementById('result').style.color= (0 < calc) ? 'green':'red'
```

```html
Result: <output id="result"></output>
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to validate the answer ;)